# Powershell and Internet Explorer Tags

Tags: windows, powershell, web

Trying to get powershell ISE to automatically go to website and click a "No" button. I have tried to get the element by tag name but its only starting Internet Explorer but after that it just can't get the element any help would be appreciated:

```
$web = "https://nam11.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flnks.gd%2Fl%2FeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJidWxsZXRpbl9saW5rX2lkIjoxMDEsInVyaSI6ImJwMjpjbGljayIsImJ1bGxldGluX2lkIjoiMjAyMTA1MTEuNDAyNjU1NjEiLCJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5mYWEuZ292L2Nvcm9uYXZpcnVzL3dlbGxuZXNzX2NoZWNrLyJ9.e4fctVtbkCtZ1yDQ2f2ZIyUCLgx3KceG4A0AIuiZTPk%2Fs%2F770634691%2Fbr%2F106182191351-l&data=04%7C01%7Csasha.tabib%40lstechllc.com%7Cb2bcd86b5a174ff6488108d914916338%7C93bb738069e94c7ca5fbfd30a5f59cc9%7C0%7C0%7C637563436952056800%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=0KULfdRzubnmWAdCqW94wE4%2F7fFTyuXSwNsCBSTGfkY%3D&reserved=0"
$ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($web)
$ie = getelementsbytagname('div')
```

The error appears as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gsb4.png)

Comment: if you search on how to execute javascript in ie from powershell probably some other questions would turn out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait a while after the `Navigate()` method to give IE time to finish.
Also, the `getElementsByTagName()` method is not a stand-alone function, but a method of the actual Document in `$ie`.

Try

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true    

$ie.Navigate("https://www.faa.gov/coronavirus/wellness_check/")
# wait for it..
while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

# find the 'NO' button and click it
($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('button') | Where-Object { $_.id -eq 'noInit' }).Click()
# wait for it..
while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

# and so on..

# when all done, release the COM object from memory
$ie.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

P.S. Your original url got me redirected to `"https://www.faa.gov/coronavirus/wellness_check/"`, so I'm using that in the code above.

Comment: Thank you it works when Internet Explorer has the unchecked protected mode. But now I need to figure out how to either loop or check three or four more questions on that website and close Internet Explorer. Again thank you I learned something today.

Comment: @Andreas Sure, I didnt go deeper than the first 'NO' button. I did add the 'wait for it..' loop after the click though, because you will need that for every step of the way.

Comment: I apologize. Thank you.